# VXWorks WatchDog timers versus Posix timers

Tags: timer, vxworks

When using timers intrerface which kind of timers one should user for general purpose application timer requirements. I understand watchdog timers are executed in ISRs so they may decrease system responsiveness if handler functions are too much CPU intensive etc. I am writing some new task which would require some general purpose timers, so which approach should i go with (timerLib or wdLib ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the code for timerLib? I wouldn't be surprised if it used the native wdLib under the covers, I don't have access to the vxworks source anymore, so I can't look myself.

Additionally wdLib is quite light weight, so long as you don't go and make wd handler routines that take 10 minutes to execute per invocation, you should be fine with native calls. I typically make my wd handlers give a sem or send a message to unblock a task that does the real work.